# Optimize function without looping through array

Tags: javascript

I've developed a small memory game, the game contains a function to flip cards for every turn. I'm looping thru the array containing the images every time to pick one card. I'm sure there's away to optimize this function so I don't have to loop thru the array every time in order to just turn one card. But I'm a bit clueless how to proceed and would like to get some guidance of how I possibly could optimize this function.

Can I create some sort of if statement perhaps? Note. Looking for vanilla javascript suggestions only and without creating an object to replace the array.

I'm clueless of another method then to loop thru the array.

```
function flipCards() {
  var i; // Loopvar

  // For loop
  for (i = 0; i < cardsElems.length; i++) {
    if (this == cardsElems[i]) {
      if (cardsCounter > 1) {
        return;
      }

      cardsElems[i].className = "brickFront";
      cardsElems[i].src = "pics/" + allCards[i] + ".png";
      removeListener(cardsElems[i], "click", flipCards);
      if (cardsCounter < 1) {
        card1 = i;
      } else {
        card2 = i;
      }
      cardsCounter += 1;
    }
    }

  if (cardsCounter < 2) {
    nextBtn.disabled = true; // Disable button
  }

  if (cardsCounter == 2) {
    turns += 1;
    turnNr.innerHTML = turns;
    nextBtn.disabled = false; // Enable button
  }

  if (brickBack.length == 0) {
    endGame();
  }
} // End flipCards
```

Comment: If your code works and you seek improvements or constructive criticism, your question is a better fit on [codereview.se]

Answer (score -1):

how about using [Loadash](https://lodash.com) ?
It has plenty of function to manipulate arrays and very efficient.

you can store your data inside an object.By key(card name) value(fliped or not). then access by the key to change the value to be flipped or not.
example : `{Ace: true}` = {'cardName': 'isFlipped'}

Comment: I forgot to mention that I want to solve this with vanilla javascript  :)

Comment: you can use store your data in object instead an array

Comment: looking for methods without creating an object :)

Comment: @luxaeterna these requirements should be in your question to avoid wasting time in the back and forth